# Como excluir um dado do BD pelo terminal do Ubuntu? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Fiz um scaffold no rails... OK. Agora to utilizando a gem paranoia para dar um software delete, mas aí é que ta, como faço pra dar o comando por exemplo desse, em um post meu? Qual o caminho...

Answer (score 1):

Para manipular um banco de dados no Linux por meio do terminal você só precisa:

1. Fazer login:

> `mysql -u root -p`: "-u" para informar o usuário, que no caso é "root"
>   e "-p" para o Linux mostrar o campo de senha, então você digita a
>   senha correta e acessa o shell do MySQL no terminal do Linux;

2. Faça suas queries como desejar:

> DELETE FROM `minha_tabela` WHERE campo = "valor";

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi bem sua pergunta. Mas vou postar algumas formas de trabalhar com registros.

Entre na pasta de sua aplicação com o terminal e digite: 
rails console

Altere o "Post" para seu model.

```
Post.delete_all #deleta todos os registros do model Post
```

Encontrando e removendo registros por id.

```
post = Post.find_by_id(5) # Encontra post de id 5 e armazena na variavel post

post.destroy #remove post
```

O find_by pode ser utilizado para outros campos. Ex "title"

```
post = Post.find_by_title("Curso de Artes")
```

Vlw!